# How to generate report using sikuli for desktop application

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automation, sikuli

I automated an application using sikuli. Now the program is full of image (usual sikuli program), I want to generate the final report for the test cases. I can only see the option for robot framework to generate the report. I don't know python. How can I do that without robot framework? Can you jus guide me with the steps to do that? if there is no option guide with the normal way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of those two:

- [HTMLTestRunner](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/212372) can be used by adding this script (and the .py file) to your currrent solution:

--script--

```
from sikuli import *
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

Class ClassName(unittest.TestCase):

#paste your script

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ClassName)
outfile = open("C:\\Sikuli\\Reports\\report.html", "w") # path to report folder
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title=' Report Title', description='desc..' )
runner.run(suite)
```

- [XMLTestRunner](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/193048) almost the same as above:

--script--

```
import xmlrunner
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        // setUp

    def testMyTest(self):
        // test

    def tearDown(self):
        // tearDown

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
result = XMLTestRunner(file("unittest.xml", "w")).run(suite)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. Where to include this scirpt and run this.. Whether in python script editor or in sikuli editor or notepad.Since am new to this i couldnt able to get u. Can u jus give me some more information (Step by Step process). Thanks in advance

Comment: I've done this a long time ago, but as far as I remember this should be added as part of your Python scripts. In the links there is more detailed description and answers (I had to use them back then). If this still doesn't solve your problem try Google for the way of including these *runners.